# PowerBuilder comparing dates

Tags: date, powerbuilder

I want to validate date of birth of employees, i.e: the birth date should not be greater than today's (current) date. I don't know much about date operations in PowerBuilder.

Comment: Why no accept? Also, I knew my children's birthdates in advance so be sure of your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In powerscript, you could do something like this:

```
if ld_birthdate > today() then
    Messagebox ("Error", "Birthdate must be before today.")
    return -1
end if
```

If you want to validate the birthdate in a datawindow, the easiest way is to find the birthdate column in the Column Specification pane and double click on Validation Expression.  This will open the expression builder where you can test your validation at design time:

[image: datawindow validation]

Answer (score 0):

You did not provided much info about how you plan to validate the date: is it in a pbscript, in a datawindow as a validation expression?

FYI, PB has both Date, Time and DateTime data formats. You have several methods to build a time/date and extract parts of them, and you can directly compare two date just like any other numerical value with `<`, `<=`, `=`, `>=`, `>`, `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking at the PFC n_cst_datetime service class.

Jason